# Full rank design matrix GLM

Tags: matrix

I have a question regarding Generalized Linear Models and its design matrix. In the GLM framework we say that $h(E(X))=Z\beta$, where $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{M\times (r+1)}$ is called a design matrix, that we assume has full rank. $h(\cdot)$ is the canonical link and $\beta$ is the parameter vector.

Now, why does the design matrix Z have to have full rank?
The MLE for $\beta$ is obtained by solving the following equation: $ZVb'(Z\beta)=Z'VX$. Is this equation numerically not solvable for a design matrix that does not have full rank?

Answer (score 0):

A standard result in linear algebra is that a matrix $X$ is invertible if and only if it is full rank.

Now for a large sample size, the approximate distribution of the ML estimator of the GLM parameters is obtained as,
$$
\widehat{\beta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta, \mathcal{I}^{-1})
$$

Where $\mathcal{I} = X^{t}WX$ is the Fisher Information evaluated at the MLE. $W$ is a diagonal matrix with elements $w_{ii} = \frac{1}{var(Y_i)}\left(\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \eta_i} \right)^2$, $\mu_i = E(Y_i)$ and $\eta_i$ is the linear predictor for sample $i$.

So if your design matrix $X$ is not full rank, then it is not invertible. Therefore, $\mathcal{I}$ is not invertible, since $\mathcal{I}^{-1} = (X^{t})^{-1}W^{-1}X^{-1}$. This would result in an undefined variance/covariance structure for $\widehat{\beta}$.In addition, one of the most popular methods of finding $\widehat{\beta}$ is by the method of scoring,
$$
\beta^{(r+1)} = \beta^{(r)} + \mathcal{I}^{-1}\frac{\partial l}{\partial \beta^{(r)}}
$$
Clearly we cannot score if $\mathcal{I}$ is not invertible.